# How to find the block type of Super Table field that is inside a Matrix field

Tags: craft3, matrix, plugin-supertable

I'm making a front-end entry form with a Super Table field that is inside a Matrix field. Super Table docs at https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/super-table/docs/template-guides/front-end-form have an example with the following code to figure out a block type of Super Table field:

```
{% set fieldHandle = 'mySuperTableField' %}
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle(fieldHandle) %}
{% set blocktype = craft.superTable.getSuperTableBlocks(field.id)[0] %}
```

If in my case I have a Matrix field with handle myMatrixFeild that contains mySuperTableField, how do I find out the block type of mySuperTableField?

Answer (score 3):

That's more complicated, because fields in a Matrix are scoped to the Matrix field, which is why you can't just go:

`{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('superTableFieldInMatrix') %}`

You'll need to loop through the Matrix's fields to find the Super Table field, then carry on as normal.

```
{% set matrixField = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('myMatrixField') %}

{% for field in matrixField.getBlockTypeFields() %}
    {% if field.handle == 'mySuperTableField' %}
        {% set blocktype = craft.superTable.getSuperTableBlocks(field.id)[0] %}
```